# How to switch between TypeScript and HTML with one (or two) shortcuts in vscode?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Working with Angular2, I often have *typescript* `@Components` with *html* template inside.

Atom supports syntax highlighting of both at the same time, while VSCode doesn't.

Right now you have to use the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> and type `"typescript"` or `"html"` in order to switch between the two, which is fine but kind of tedious when developing new components.

I'd like to bind shortcuts change language on the fly using the `"workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode"` command into the `keybindings.json` file.
Ideally would be something like this:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+win+h", "command": "workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode", **toggle="html,typescript"**  }
```

but would be also ok something like this:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+win+h", "command": "workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode", **value="html"**  }

{ "key": "ctrl+win+t", "command": "workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode", **value="typescript"**  }
```

Obviously the point is that `keybindings.json` doesn't support the `"value"` field.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I have all of my html in their own `component.html` files and just tab back and forth.. but would love to know an answer to this!

Comment: @Zze  angular2-inline extension is the answare

Answer (score 11):

I have installed **Angular Switcher** from my Visual Studio Code extensions.
This extension provides two commands as following:

- **extension.ionSwitchHTML**  for Switching to the corresponding .html file
- **extension.ionSwitchTS**    for Switching to the corresponding.ts file

Then I open the Keyboard Shortcuts using Shortcut key: [**Ctrl+k, Ctrl+S**]

or File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.
After that, I searched by keyword: ***ionSwitch*** that show me the above two commands.

Then I clicked each of the commands for keybinding as I felt comfort like:
***Ctrl+Shift+H*** and ***Ctrl+Shift+T*** respectively.

[image: Angular Switcher Shortcuts]

For **angular-2 switcher** extension, same procedure as the above.

[image: angular-2 switcher]

This makes coding easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If I understand you correctly then you want to switch between your html template and your typescript code.
There is an extension for this available called angular2-switcher.

Available here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=infinity1207.angular2-switcher

Comment: Still valid in 2024 January. Someone mentioned the Angular extension does this, but it does not. It is this extension that provides the behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Something like your `"value"` field *does* exist for keybindings, namely `"args"`. It's mentioned [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_insert-snippets) with an example for the `insertSnippet` command.

Unfortunately, it seems like the `changeLanguageMode` command does currently *not* support any `args`. This was discussed in this unresolved feature request: [#1800](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1800)

It's also not possible to do this using the VSCode extension API, as mentioned in the above issue. [`TextDocument#languageId`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1.9.1/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L106) is `readonly`.

Regarding HTML support in TypeScript files, there's a relevant issue here: [#2000](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2000)

In summary, it looks like you will have to wait for one of these two feature requests to be implemented.

The only alternative I can think of would be to [write your own extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensions/example-hello-world) including a modified TypeScript grammar. You would have to adjust it to inject HTML highlighting at the correct place. In case you're interested in doing that:

- The source for the TS grammar file can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-TmLanguage/blob/master/TypeScript.YAML-tmLanguage).
- [Here's](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2793#issuecomment-221093247) some information on how you would go about injecting one grammar into another.

Comment: Thanks to your links I've been able to find the vscode extension "angular2-inline" which does exactly what I wanted.

this is the extension link

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=natewallace.angular2-inline

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

Vscode's Angular extension now natively supports two commands:

- Go to Component
- Go to Template

Just assign hotkeys (Ctrl-K Ctrl-S), and you're done :)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link or the extension name?

Comment: @Colin sure, it's [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template)

Answer (score 1):

I found this very handy generic file switcher extension **File Switcher**. It cycles through related files.

Default key binding is `alt+[` and `alt+]` to go prev and next file. However simply use one key binding to rotate between files. I just re-mapped `alt+[` to `alt+q` for my own convenience.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adrianwilczynski.simple-switcher

Answer (score 1):

I find this extension “file-ext-switch” in vscode.
this is my configuration in
`~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json` for mac

```
...

    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+j",
        "command": "fileextswitch",
        "args": { "extensions": [".wxml",".html"], "useOtherColumn": true }, 
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+k",
        "command": "fileextswitch",
        "args": { "extensions": [".js", ".ts"], "useOtherColumn": true }, 
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
        "command": "fileextswitch",
        "args": { "extensions": [ ".less",".css", ".scss"], "useOtherColumn": true }, 
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+;",
        "command": "fileextswitch",
        "args": { "extensions": [".json",".spec.ts"], "useOtherColumn": true }, 
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
...
```